# Angular CLI throws error: 'mat-tab-nav-panel' is not a known element

Tags: angular

I am working on my angular project and on a specific section, I need to implement Material Tab Nav Bar (as shown working on [tab material component page](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/examples)).

Here's the HTML:

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar [tabPanel]="tabPanel">
<a mat-tab-link (click)= "SomeMethod()" > Office </a>
<a mat-tab-link (click)= "SomeOtherMethod()" > NHIU </a>
<a mat-tab-link (click)= "AnotherMethod()" > TIU </a>
</nav>

<mat-tab-nav-panel #tabPanel></mat-tab-nav-panel>
```

The **< nav mat-tab-nav-bar >** works fine without the **[tabPanel]** directive and without the **<mat-tab-nav-panel #tabPanel>**

But when using **tab panel** and **nav panel**, angular cli throws following errors:

> error NG8002: Can't bind to 'tabPanel' since it isn't a known property
> of 'nav'.
>
> < nav mat-tab-nav-bar [tabPanel]="tabPanel" >
>
> 1. If 'mat-tab-nav-panel' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'mat-tab-nav-panel' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>    to suppress this message.

> error NG8001: 'mat-tab-nav-panel' is not a known element:
>
> 1. If 'mat-tab-nav-panel' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'mat-tab-nav-panel' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>    to suppress this message.
>
> <mat-tab-nav-panel #tabPanel></ mat-tab-nav-panel>

I have already imported MatTabsModule in my material module and vanilla mat-tabs also works fine in the project.

Cannot understand what the problem is here. Please help.

Comment: Which version of angular-matrial are you on ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

mat-tab-nav-panel is a component introduced in AngularMaterial v13.2.0 . Are you sure your current version of AngularMaterial is above 13.2 ?

Comment: Well, version was the problem indeed.  I was at version 13.1.1.

Comment: The project does not throw errors any more, but the tabs still do not render properly. The bottom line does not show under the tabs.

Comment: I'm, on `@angular/material@15.2.8` and I do have the same problem

Comment: Nevermind, I had to `import {MatTabsModule} from '@angular/material/tabs';` which was neither suggested in the intellisense, nor documented in the TS component example on the website