# Can't get mat-tab-group to function, it keeps throwing an MatTabHeader._checkPaginationEnabled error

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-tab

I used the code straight from the Angular Material website [https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview], and I believe I followed it slavishly, but clearly I've done something wrong because I can't get it to load, well the mat-tab appears, but the error also appears immediately in the console.

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kugQe.jpg) Any help GREATLY appreciated.

I followed two different tutorials, and loaded my app.module.ts correctly (I believe) but I'm guessing there is some configuration thing that I don't know about, because nothing I've tried has removed this error.

[app.module.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAKdw.jpg)
[app.component.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZJ4o.jpg)

Comment: Check if you has a variable called "tab" in your .ts, if true, rename the variable. NOTE: When we use a template reference variable (in your case the `#tab`) it's like you declare a variable in .ts

Comment: Thanks for your reply Eliseo, I checked and that doesn't seem to be it, I changed it to #tabGroup, but the same error is occurring.
It seems to be something to do with the inkbar, but what that is, and how to fix it, I sadly still have no idea.

Comment: it's possible the error it's not in the mat-tab else in another component you has not imported the module :(

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks again, I will go away and check that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, discovered the solution (finally), with thanks to [Angular CLI throws error: 'mat-tab-nav-panel' is not a known element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71101178/angular-cli-throws-error-mat-tab-nav-panel-is-not-a-known-element)

The problem began when I used the `ng add` command from the Angular Material [website](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started): `*ng add @angular/material*`, and this added the version of Angular Material version 7.0.0 to my project.

List here:

```
 @angular-devkit/architect       0.1402.10    
 @angular-devkit/build-angular   14.2.10    
 @angular-devkit/core            14.2.10    
 @angular-devkit/schematics      14.1.3    
 @angular/cli                    14.1.3    
 @angular/material               7.0.0    
 @schematics/angular             14.1.3    
 rxjs                            7.5.7    
 typescript                      4.7.4
```

Thinking version 7 seems way too old, I then created a fresh Angular project with: `*ng new test_4*`, went to the NPM website, and—following Benoit's answer—found a version of Angular Material that should work, version 13.3.9, and installed that in my project using: `*npm i @angular/material@13.3.9*`. The new project's details:

```
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1402.10
@angular-devkit/build-angular   14.2.10
@angular-devkit/core            14.2.10
@angular-devkit/schematics      14.1.3
@angular/cli                    14.1.3
@angular/material               13.3.9
@schematics/angular             14.1.3
rxjs                            7.5.7
typescript                      4.7.4
```

Once I did that, `mat-tab-group` began working fine.

Hope this may help others as new to Angular as I am.